# Terminal progress bars not displaying in the Docker console.

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, terminal

Im trying to include one of npm's terminal progress bars to better visualize how a long process is progressing. When I run it from the standard "node index.js" it goes off without a hitch, but when running from a simple docker image, nothing is posted to the terminal. My index.js reads as such:

```
const _cliProgress = require('cli-progress');

// create a new progress bar instance and use shades_classic theme
const bar1 = new _cliProgress.Bar({}, _cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);

// start the progress bar with a total value of 200 and start value of 0
bar1.start(200, 0);

// update the current value in your application..
bar1.update(100);

// stop the progress bar
bar1.stop();
```

And this is my docker file:

```
FROM node:latest

#create work directory
RUN mkdir -p /src

#establish the app folder as the work directory
WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json /src

COPY package-lock.json /src

RUN npm i

COPY . /src

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

The terminal displays nothing from these packages but does display the normal console.logs.This problem exists for the other package I tried to use as well.

Any information on why this is having a different than the expected result would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run docker, with `--tty , -t` flag, which will allocate a pseudo-TTY

```
docker run -t --rm test
```

You can check the following questions for a more detailed explanation on that flag:

[Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

[What does it mean to attach a tty/std-in-out to dockers or lxc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272401/what-does-it-mean-to-attach-a-tty-std-in-out-to-dockers-or-lxc)

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.

Comment: One more question if you have the time, if I run this inside of a docker-compose swarm(?) then what would be the process of replicating this.  Would it be "tty: true" inside the image's yml node?

Comment: Yes, the equivalent on docker-compose.yml would be `tty: true`