# kubernetes setting tty to false not working as (I) expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, tty

Consider the following manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container2
    image: varunuppal/nonrootsudo
    tty: false
    stdin: false
```

I have read here that tty indicates "

```
Whether this container should allocate a TTY for itself
```

so If understand it well, setting it to false, it should not be possible to run into the container with kubectl exec -ti firstpod bash. However, I am still able to do it !!!

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886146/kubectl-attach-unable-to-use-a-tty-container-es-node-did-not-allocate-one) bu my problem is the "other way" : I set tty to false but still can execute commands in the container

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl exec` is a *debugging tool* that spawns an additional process inside an existing pod's container.  That additional process can independently have a virtual tty attached to it, or not.  Separately, you can also usually run an interactive shell with or without a tty attached to it, so long as it can still read commands from its stdin and write responses to its stdout.

In practice you should almost never need to set `tty: true` for a Kubernetes container.  Setting it or not only affects the main process in the container and not anything you launch with `kubectl exec` or other similar debugging tools.

If your goal here is to prevent `kubectl exec` then you need to use the Kubernetes permissions system to disallow it.  In some cases it may be possible to build a very hardened container that doesn't contain a shell, which would also effectively disable `kubectl exec` (though it also makes some kinds of debugging much harder); this is only really possible if you're using a compiled language and don't need a complex launcher script (most often, a `FROM scratch` image for a statically-linked Go program).

Comment: Thks David for your you answer. My interest is actually didactic and my intention is to understand how the tty: true/false works and how I can check it. maybe a link or (even better) a small command to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not so while ago I came across this dive in [article](https://erkanerol.github.io/post/how-kubectl-exec-works/) into `kubectl exec` which i think you may find interesting.

Second is this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272401/what-does-it-mean-to-attach-a-tty-std-in-out-to-dockers-or-lxc) case where one of the community user go thru and shows couple of process differences with container started with `-i` and -`t` and without those.

Last thing worth to mention that you also have `kubectl attach` to your disposal:

> In addition to interactive execution of commands, you can now also
> attach to any running process. Like kubectl logs, you’ll get stderr
> and stdout data, but with attach, you’ll also be able to send stdin
> from your terminal to the program. Awesome for interactive debugging,
> or even just sending ctrl-c to a misbehaving application.

The differences here is that the process you interact with.   `Attach` will interact with the one currently running (there is no choice).